# what is node number a particular result extracted in ansys.dpf.post (pyansys) in python?

Tags: python, ansys

I have extracted the elastic strain energy density at each node in python from an ansys .rst file using ansys dpf post (solution.misc.nodal_elastic_strain_energy_density) but dont know the information about the nodes at which the results are extracted. I think the results are extracted in a random node manner. So can anyone suggest me to get the results according to the node format that was given in ansys mechanical Or atleast know the node number at the result in python.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the docs are [a bit thin](https://postdocs.pyansys.com/examples/02-Detailed-Examples/03-result_keywords.html#ref-result-keywords) but I think you can explicitly specify the nodes you are interested in with a keyword:

```
nodal_elastic_strain_energy_density_scoped = solution.misc.nodal_elastic_strain_energy_density(
    location=post.locations.nodal, node_scoping=[1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: do you have extracted this example from a relevant *link*  or documentation?

Comment: I extracted it from the given link and adapted it to the result requested in the question.